# Catkin_make on a Raspberry Pi 4 gives error with ros-i2cpwmboard

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a follow up from my previous question, about geometry_msgs not being found in catkin_ws, after I had installed ROS Noetic on a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B. The previous thread can be found [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/371286/cant-use-geometry_msgs-on-a-raspberry-pi-4/)

I was able to get geometry_msgs by downloading common_msgs from the ROS Github page - though for some reason I couldn't download only the geometry_msgs folder and had to download the entire common_msgs package.
However, catkin_make still does not work. I added geometry_msgs to the dependencies in the package.xml folder for the ros-i2cpwmboard package, and to the two lines in the CMakeList.txt for that package (which lines are specified in the previous thread). I end up getting this error:

```
/home/pi/catkin_ws/src/ros-i2cpwmboard/src/i2cpwm_controller.cpp:422:15:
error: ‘i2c_smbus_read_byte_data’ was not declared in this scope
     oldmode = i2c_smbus_read_byte_data (_controller_io_handle, __MODE1);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I looked at a similar thread with Opencv, but I don't think that thread applies to this package.
Anyone know what could be the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/371342/catkin_make-on-a-raspberry-pi-4-gives-error-with-ros-i2cpwmboard/) by [RobotHunter](https://answers.ros.org/users/69545/robothunter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2021-02-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to fix this using the solution found [here](https://gitlab.com/bradanlane/ros-i2cpwmboard/-/issues/4)

---

Edit: Right, sorry about that.
The solution comes from a user named Louise Radtke.

"At first, I installed libi2c-dev.
Then, I added i2c into line 22 of src/ros-i2cpwmboard/CMakeLists.txt, so that it looks like:

```
target_link_libraries(i2cpwm_board ${catkin_LIBRARIES} i2c)
```

And as mentioned in this post from Nvidia Devtalk, I added

```
extern "C" {
    #include <i2c/smbus.h>
}
```

to src/ros-i2cpwmboard/src/i2cpwm_controller.cpp. Now it's fine. :)
I am using Ubuntu 18.04."

Specifically, I added the extern C function at line 268, above the line `#define MAX_BOARDS 62`

---

Originally posted by [RobotHunter](https://answers.ros.org/users/69545/robothunter/) with karma: 36 on 2021-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-02-09**:
Please don't post link-only answers.

Copy the relevant parts into your answer here using quotes.